# Swift2でRealmのデータを読み出したい。

Tags: swift, realm

Realmを勉強中です。

サンプルやマニュアルを見ているのですが、いまいちわからず・・・

ID 読み　登録データ　Time
1   かお　(^^)         2010-01-01 00:00:00
2   かお　(^^;         2010-01-01 00:00:01

上記データで、Timeでソートしながら「か」で「(^^)」と「(^^;」などのデータを読みだしたいのです。

下記コードはリスト化とソートがわからずに書いています。

そして、使った行のTimeだけ現在時刻で更新したいのです。

わかる方、教えていただけたら幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
extension String : CollectionType {}

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    var DBdir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

・・・

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    ・・・
    }

・・・

    func btnDown11(sender: UIButton){
        self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    func btnUp11(sender: AnyObject){
        self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            tText = "か"
            InsertText(tText)
     }

     func btnDownEnter(sender: UIButton){
        self.buttonEnter.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
     }

    func btnUpEnter(sender: UIButton){
         self.buttonEnter.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.7, alpha: 1.0)
         let proxy = textDocumentProxy
         proxy.insertText("\n")
         //この辺で唯一の使ったデータの日時更新
        dic.date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2014-01-01 00:00:03")!; //日時後日固定でなく自動取得に変更
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(path: realmPath)

            realm.write {
                realm.add(dic)
           }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

    }


    ・・・

    func InsertText (str: String){
        tText = ""
        //この辺で変換「リスト」の取得
        // Query using a predicate string
        var tanDic = dic.objectsWhere("color = 'str' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'")

        // Query using an NSPredicate object
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "読み = %@ AND name BEGINSWITH %@", str, "B")
        tanDic = Dog.objectsWithPredicate(predicate)
        //ここでリスト表示            
        print(tanDic)

        let proxy = textDocumentProxy
        proxy.insertText(str)
     }

}
```

Comment: 書かれたコードを差し支えない範囲でできるだけ多く載せてください。この投稿からではあなたがどこまで理解していて、どこで困っているのかが分かりません。

Comment: 今エラーの出ない範囲で追記いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: モデルは問題ないですね。データを保存しているところと、問題の検索しているところのコードも載せてください。そこが無いと、何がおかしいのかが分かりません。

Comment: いろいろ試してますが、ダメてバッサリ消してしまいました・・・
候補を羅列するのに何を使うべきか（ボタンかラベルなのか？）も悩んでいて、未確定なコードになってしまっています。

Comment: わかる範囲で書き足しました。皆さんがしておられる、候補を1行に次々表示して横スクロールする方法を今調べていますが、わからず詰まってます。

Comment: わかる範囲でコード書きました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

だいたい何をやろうとされてるのか理解しました。

ボタンから入力された文字を受け取って、データベースからその文字で始まるデータを変換候補として表示して、選択された候補については`date`を更新して次からは先頭に表示されるようにしたい、とかそんな感じでしょうか。

そうだとすると、まずモデルの定義は間違ってはいませんが、少し修正したほうがいいです。
クラス名は大文字で始めるようにしましょう。
これはアップルが使用しているルールなので、それに合わせるほうが読みやすくなります。

また、`date`プロパティの初期値は現在時刻のほうがいいでしょう。
なぜなら、選択された変換候補が先頭に来るように並べ替えるのであれば、初期値が現在時刻のほうが都合が良いからです。

そうするとモデルクラスは下記のようになります。

```
class Dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}
```

変換候補として表示するデータはあらかじめ保存されている必要がありますので、顔文字のデータを保存しましょう。
ご提示の顔文字のデータを２件挿入するコードは下記のようになります。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dic1 = Dic()
    dic1.ID = 1
    dic1.yomi = "かお"
    dic1.emoji = "(^^)"

    let dic2 = Dic()
    dic2.ID = 2
    dic2.yomi = "かお"
    dic2.emoji = "(^^;"

    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.write { () in
        realm.add(dic1, update: true)
        realm.add(dic2, update: true)
    }
}
```

次に、入力された文字から始まる変換候補を検索する例は下記になります。
とりあえず、入力された文字は固定で"か"ということにします。

`yomi`プロパティが`inputText`で始まるデータを検索し、`date`プロパティの降順に並べ替えています。

お分かりかと思いますが、`inputText`変数に違う文字が入れば、異なる結果になります。

```
let inputText = "か"
let results = realm.objects(Dic)
    .filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText)
    .sorted("date", ascending: false)
```

これで、`results`に変換候補としての検索結果が入っているので、取り出すには下記のようにします。

ループで取り出す以外にも、`results[0]`や`results[1]`などとして、１件目、２件目を取り出すこともできます。

```
for result in results {
    print(result)

    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.write { () in
        result.date = NSDate()
    }
}
```

そして、上記のコードではループして取り出した`Dic`オブジェクトの`date`プロパティを現在時刻で更新しています。
これを応用すると、選択された変換候補は次の検索から先頭に表示される、ということが実現できると思います。

Comment: `let results = realm.objects(Dic).filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText) .sorted("date", ascending: false)`のrealmでエラーになってしまいます。import RealmSwiftしていますが、何が問題なのでしょうか？Use of unresolved identifier 'realm'
どうも、OSXではうまくいく？ようなんですが、iOSではなぜでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージの通りで文法が間違っているので、エラーメッセージを読む習慣を付けるとともに、プログラミングの基本と文法について学ばれたほうが良いと思います。それはさておき、"Use of unresolved identifier 'realm'"ということなので`realm`という名前の変数がそれ以前に定義されていないのでコンパイラがその変数が分からずにエラーを出しているということです。"realm"変数をインスタンス変数として持つか、毎回`let realm = try! Realm()`として変数に格納します。

Comment: 初心者ですみません。コンパイルは頂いた助言で通るようになりましたが、実行時に別のエラーと思われるものが出ます。 _dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/830BF1AF-9059-445F-AC17-FC40D97C9C6E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9D7F484F-0512-49EE-92B4-9F00FCB00351/test.app/PlugIns/test-key.appex/test-key
  Reason: image not found_  　　　Swift2の仕様が決まり、マニュアル本が出たら、基本を学びたいと思います。

Comment: 実行時にフレームワークが見つからないというエラーなので、フレームワークをターゲットのバンドルに含めるようにプロジェクトを設定する必要があります。元の質問と関係なくなっているのと、これについてコメント欄で回答するのは不可能なので必要なら新しく質問を作ってください。

Comment: 別途質問をいたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。